# Training accuracy on SGD

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

How do you compute for the training accuracy for SGD? Do you compute it using the batch data you trained your network with? Or using the entire dataset? (for each batch optimization iteration)

I tried computing the training accuracy for each iteration using the batch data I trained my network with. And it almost always gives me 100% training accuracy (sometimes 100%, 90%, 80%, always multiples of 10%, but the very first iteration gave me 100%). Is this because I am computing the accuracy on the same batch data I trained it with for that iteration? Or is my model overfitting that it gave me 100% instantly, but the validation accuracy is low? (this is the main question here, if this is acceptable, or there is something wrong with the model)

Here are the hyperparameters I used.

```
batch_size = 64
kernel_size = 60 #from 60 #optimal 2
depth = 15 #from 60 #optimal 15
num_hidden = 1000 #from 1000 #optimal 80

learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 8

total_batches = train_x.shape[0] // batch_size
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the training accuracy on the batch data during the training process is correct. If the number of the accuracy is always multiple of 10%, then most likely it is because your batch size is 10. For example, if 8 of the training outputs match the labels, then your training accuracy will be 80%. If the training accuracy number goes up and down, there are two main possibilities:
1. If you print out the accuracy numbers multiple time over one epoch, it is normal, especially at the early stage of training, because the model is predicting over different data samples;
2. If you print out the accuracy once each epoch, and if you see the training accuracy goes up and down during the later stage of the training, that means your learning rate is too big. You need to decease that overtime during the training.
If these do not answer your question, please provider more details so that we can help.

Comment: Wow! Yes my batch size was 10! That was amazing. However, how do you suggest I go about "decreasing the learning rate over time"?

Comment: I am using Adam Optimizer

Comment: You can use the learning rate decay method, or you can construct your model by having the learning rate as a placeholder and then feed the values you want as if you feed the training batch data during the training. However, it looks like your learning rate 1e-4 is small enough.

Comment: Hmm yes, what do you think is the problem if my learning rate is already small enough? I posted the hyperparameters I used.

Comment: But there are adaptive learning rate algorithms right? One of them is Adam?

Comment: It is not adaptive by itself. You have to explicitly change it. Firstly, I suggest  you do not print out the training accuracy very a few steps, but over a whole epoch, with an average of all steps in that epoch. Secondly, start with a bigger learning rate, such as 4e-4, and then decrease it overtime. This is not just to accelerate the training, but also can avoid your model to get to local optima in the early stage.

Comment: "with an average of all steps in that epoch" what do you mean by this?

Comment: For example, you can store the training accuracy in each step in a python list, and when it reaches about an epoch (all training set data are gone over once), you calculate the mean of all the items in the list (and then clear the list). That would be more stable to monitor.